# How to use a database for merge after download?

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I'm using Ormlite, for my android app, to store my data. I want to download a database from a site and after this, the program checks if a database exists. If a database exists, then the new database and the old database should merge.
Here comes my problem. In Ormlite you create a Dao to interact with the tables of a database and I wanted to know, how I can interact with the new database after the download?

For example:
Database A from the app has the items:

Cheese, Eggs, Milk, Chicken

Database B from the download has the items:

Cheese, Eggs, Milk, Flour, Bread

At the end I want:

Cheese, Eggs, Milk, Flour, Bread, Chicken and only one database left.

And to clarify: Yes, it exists questions "How to merge databases". 

 For example: 
[Android update - merge database contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898866/android-update-merge-database-contents) 
But that is not my problem. I want to know, how to interact with the new database with Ormlite. Which way exists, that I can get access to the new database?

Edit:

 I tried to download the database and guarantee that the version is always higher than the old database version. Therefore, at least that what I thought, it would go in OnUpgrade method and there I could merge the database. But i just replaced the old database. 
I also tried to make a second OrmDBHelper with another name, so after the download I could use the methods there. But no errors or anything whatsoever.

 Here is the database helper from the existing database and the second one is the same, except the name.

```
public class OrmDbHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

public static final String LOG = OrmDbHelper.class.getName();
public static final String DB_NAME = "bestand.db";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public OrmDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath()
            + File.separator + DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    try {
        TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, ScanItem.class);
        TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, BestandItem.class);
        TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, SettingsItem.class);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Log.e(LOG, "Error Creating table", ex);
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    try {
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, ScanItem.class, true);
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, BestandItem.class, true);
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, SettingsItem.class, true);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, ScanItem.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, BestandItem.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, SettingsItem.class);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Log.e(LOG, "Error Updating table", ex);
    }
}

public Dao<ScanItem, Integer> createScanItemDAO() {
    try {
        return DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, ScanItem.class);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Log.e(LOG, "Error Creating DAO for Todo class", ex);
    }
    return null;
}

public Dao<BestandItem, Integer> createBestandItemDAO() {
    try {
        return DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, BestandItem.class);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Log.e(LOG, "Error Creating DAO for Todo class", ex);
    }
    return null;
}

public Dao<SettingsItem, Integer> createSettingItemDAO() {
    try {
        return DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, SettingsItem.class);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Log.e(LOG, "Error Creating DAO for Todo class", ex);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

And here is how I tried to get access to the second database:
The access to the first database works, but to the second one doesnt. I even checked if the download of the second database works, which it does.

```
public class OrmDataHelper {

private Dao<ScanItem, Integer> scanItemDAO;
private Dao<BestandItem, Integer> bestandItemDAO;
private Dao<SettingsItem, Integer> settingsItemsDAO;

public OrmDataHelper(Context context) {
    OrmDbHelper ormDbHelper = new OrmDbHelper(context);
     scanItemDAO = ormDbHelper.createScanItemDAO();
     bestandItemDAO = ormDbHelper.createBestandItemDAO();
     settingsItemsDAO = ormDbHelper.createSettingItemDAO();
}

public ArrayList<ScanItem> getAllScanItem() {
    ArrayList<ScanItem> temp = null;
    try {
         temp = new ArrayList<>(scanItemDAO.queryForAll());
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far

Comment: I tried to download the database and guarantee that the version is always higher than the old database version. Therefore, at least that what I thought, it would go in OnUpgrade method and there I could merge the database. But i just replaced the old database.

Comment: What SQL commands have you tried?  Can you show some code?

Comment: Sure, just added it to the question. This is the code from my second attempt.